# How do I convert a decimal value to a varchar value

Tags: sql-server

I have value contains decimal (15,7) as datatype. It contains 5 digits after decimal point. My value is : 123.1071570. When I try to convert the value into "varchar" then in the Output I get 123.107. I want result as 123.107157 after converting the value into varchar.

What I have tried:

```
DECLARE @test1 decimal(15,7),
        @test2 nvarchar(10)

SELECT @test1 = 123.1071570

--Case 1 :
SELECT cast(@test1 as float) AS value1  
-- output : 123.107157  -- Value which I got after using cast()

-- I want to concate the value with string, so I need to convert it to varchar,
SELECT 'value is: '+convert(varchar,cast(@test1 as float)) AS value2     
-- output 
-- value is: 123.107  ---- Value which I got after converting it to varchar

-- Case 2 : 
SELECT convert(DOUBLE PRECISION, @test1)  AS value1  
-- output : 123.107157  -- Value which I got after using DOUBLE


SELECT 'value is: '+convert(varchar,convert(DOUBLE PRECISION, @test1)) AS value2     
-- output 
-- value is: 123.107  ---- Value which I got after converting it to varchar
```

I want Output as : "value is: 123.107157"

I want to remove trailing zeros from my value. 
My value can be anything, but after using Cast() of Double , when I convert it to varchar I want the same result which I got from cast or Double.

Comment: How does `123.107157` become `123.10705` - thats no obvious rounding!

Comment: Sorry to ask but is this something that should be happening in the database? It sounds like something that belongs in the business layer, where it is much easier to do.

Comment: Firstly, you [should always specify a length when converting to, or declaring a `VARCHAR`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), secondly if you **must** do it in SQL server, and not in the presentation layer, and you are using `SQL Server 2012+` then you can use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx) with a general number type format, e.g. `SELECT FORMAT(@test1, 'g15')`

Comment: @GarethD thanks for the answer. Its working in sql server 2012+. But I want the same result from sql serer 5+. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: It could be done with a scalar function for older versions, but I cannot stress enough that this is not a job for SQL Server. Stop trying to ram a square peg into a round hole, admit that the hole is round, and find a new peg. That is to say, just [do your formatting in the presentation Layer.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/02/19/sql-tip-keep-your-presentation-logic-in-your-presentation-layer.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky XML (starting since SQL Server 2008) :)

```
DECLARE @x xml

DECLARE @t TABLE (
    digit decimal(15,7)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(123.1071570),
(123.1200000),
(123.0000000)

SELECT @x = (
    SELECT digit as d
    FROM @t
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT 'Value is: '+CAST(t.c.query('. cast as xs:decimal?') as nvarchar(max))
FROM @x.nodes('/d') as t(c)
```

Output:

```
Value is: 123.107157
Value is: 123.12
Value is: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned here : [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (15, 7);
SET @myval = 123.1071570;
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(15,7), CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), @myval));
```

as you mentioned in comment you can use this if you don't have fix length :

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (15, 7);
SET @myval = 123.1200000 ;
SELECT CASt(CAST(CAST(@myval AS DECIMAL(15, 7)) AS FLOAT) AS NVARCHAR(255))
```

Comment: This one is not correct. I have mention in my question that , I want to remove trailing zero's. means If my value is 12.000000 then output will be 12, If my value is 123.1200000 then output will be 123.12, same as if my value is 123.1071570 then it should be 123.107157.

Comment: so chage it to decimal(15,6) , in the last line. but if you have fixed length

Comment: ur answer is not correct, when I used 123.1071570 in place of 123.1200000

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this approach:

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (15, 7);
SET @myval = 123.1071570;
SELECT CAST(CAST(@myval AS DECIMAL(15, 7)) AS FLOAT)
```

Result: `123.107157`

Comment: with the help of @Arulkumar I edit my answer and this is your need

Answer (score 0):

Simply  jsut cast the value as nvarchar.

Use below query.

```
DECLARE @test1 decimal(15,7),
    @test2 nvarchar(10)

SET @test1 = 123.1071570

SELECT cast(@test1 as nvarchar(20)) AS value1
```